# Why does using the modified Kepler's 3rd law and using the gravitational parameter yields different results?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, celestial-mechanics

$p^2=\frac{2\pi a^3}{\mu}$ ($p$ is the orbital period in seconds) gives slightly different result from $p^2=\frac{4\pi^2}{GM_1}a^3$.

Answer (score 2):

> $p^2=\frac{2\pi a^3}{\mu}$

I'm assuming this is a typo, that you meant $p^2 = \frac {4 \pi^2 a^3}{\mu}$.

> Why does using the modified Kepler's 3rd law and using the gravitational parameter yields different results?

The standard gravitational parameter $\mu$ for some body is conceptually defined as the product of the Newtonian gravitational constant and the body's mass, $\mu = GM$. However, the relationship between the period, the semi-major axis length, and $\mu$ means that $\mu$ is deducible from observations. The value of $\mu$ is known to many decimal places of accuracy for some bodies.

We can't put a celestial body on a scale and assess it's mass. Instead, the body's mass is defined in terms of the body's gravitational parameter $\mu$ and the gravitational constant: $M = \frac {\mu}G$. Another way to look at it: The observed gravitational parameter is the high precision scale by which scientists assess the masses of objects in the solar system.

Unfortunately, this scale isn't very precise. The problem is that the gravitational constant $G$ is only known to four places of accuracy. Even if $\mu$ is known to ten places of accuracy, the limited accuracy of $G$ limits the mass to four places of accuracy. The product $GM$ is not equal to $\mu$ when the mass is properly truncated to four places. This is the key reason you see a discrepancy between using $\mu$ and $GM$.

**An example**
I'll use the Sun as a specific example. According to google, $GM_\odot$ is [1.32754125×10<sup>20</sup> m<sup>3</sup>/s<sup>2</sup>](https://www.google.com/search?rls=en&q=G*(solar+mass)). This is incorrect, for a number of reasons.

- Apparently google is using 6.67408×10<sup>-11</sup> m<sup>3</sup>/kg/s<sup>2</sup> for the gravitational constant and 1.9891×10<sup>30</sup> kg for the mass of the Sun.
- The google result should have been truncated to the precision of the inputs. Google doesn't know how to do that.
- Google calculated using the current (CODATA 2014) value of the gravitational constant. What about the solar mass value of 1.9891×10<sup>30</sup> kg? There's no telling where google calculator obtained that value.
- Wikipedia currently has the value of (1.98855±0.00025)×10<sup>30</sup> kg for the solar mass, which apparently is a bit of personal research (wikipedia is not supposed to have any of that) using the 2012 value of $GM_\odot$ and the 2010 value of $G$.
- Perhaps an older version of the wikipedia article on the solar mass? Digging way back in wiki history to before 22 June 2008 yields a value of 1.9891×10<sup>30</sup> kg for the solar mass.
- Using old values or inconsistently calculated values will inevitably produce errors.

The current best estimates of the solar gravitational parameter are (as of this date) 1.32712440041×10<sup>20</sup> m<sup>3</sup>/s<sup>2</sup> in TDB-compatible units, or 1.32712442099×10<sup>20</sup> m<sup>3</sup>/s<sup>2</sup> in TCB-compatible units. The difference between the two is a result of general relativity and how one measures time and distance. See http://maia.usno.navy.mil/NSFA/NSFA_cbe.html#GMS2012 for more info.

Comment: Your explanation for the discrepancy that gravitational parameters can be computed accurately for some bodies while the gravitational constant is only known to 4 decimal places clarifies  the problem. thank you for he insight.

Answer (score 1):

A more precise form of Kepler's Third Law is written as:

$p^2 = \frac{4\pi^2}{G(M_1+M_2)}a^3$

which takes into account the mass of the orbiting body as well.  If you don't take into account the second mass, $M_2$, it will probably produce a small difference.

Comment: The $\mu$ in this question isn't the reduced mass. It's the standard gravitational parameter, conceptually defined as $\mu = GM$.

Comment: I edited my answer to correct for this.  Thanks for pointing that out.  I noticed the discrepancy in the other equation and made an assumption, and a poor one at that.